# Cкрипт формы фидбэка

Tags: php, html

Здравствуйте, господа. Нужна Ваша помощь.
Есть форма обратной связи и php скрипт файл к ней

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="feedback" role="form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Имя</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First & Last Name" >


        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ваш Email</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="example@domain.com" >

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Сообщение</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="message"></textarea>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="human" class="col-sm-2 control-label">2 + 3 = ?</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="human" name="human" placeholder="Your Answer">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">

            <?php echo $result; ?>  
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $human = intval($_POST['human']);
        $from = 'Demo Contact Form'; 
        $to = 'piskunovalxy@gmail.com'; 
        $subject = 'Message from Contact Demo ';

        $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }

        // Check if email has been entered and is valid
        if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
        }

        //Check if message has been entered
        if (!$_POST['message']) {
            $errMessage = 'Please enter your message';
        }
        //Check if simple anti-bot test is correct
        if ($human !== 5) {
            $errHuman = 'Your anti-spam is incorrect';
        }
if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! I will be in touch</div>';
        header ('Location: index.html');
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

Проблема в том, что сообщения то приходят, если все поля заполнены, в том числе и анти спам. Но если одно поле пустое или анти спам не верен, то выбивает белую страницу скрипта. 
Заранее спасибо

Comment: ну так а где else для `if (!$errName && !$errEmail && !$errMessage && !$errHuman)`?

Comment: Могу. В случае, если эта проверка не проходит - переменная `$result` остаётся неопределённой.

Comment: Если сообщение отправляется - у вас там редирект. Оно просто не успевает отобразиться

Answer (score 1):

У вас в форме стоит:

```
<?php echo $result; ?>
```

а в php-файле после последнего else нет echo. Поэтому $result не выводится. Попробуйте:

```
echo $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
```

Либо редирект тогда также с него добавьте на index, как в первом условии.

На будущее: в таких случаях всегда есть смысл попробовать var_dump() для всех переменных, поведение которых вызывает сомнение.